# onClientConnectionState called multiple times on successful connection

Tags: android, connection, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I'm connecting to BLE device and got two identical onClientConnectionState() calls with identical status. Is this supposed to call multiple times or i doing something wrong? Here the log:

```
05-06 22:48:31.778 I/BluetoothDevice(17325): createBond() for device D5:...:EA called by pid: 17325 tid: 17360
05-06 22:48:31.813 D/BluetoothGatt(17325): connect() - device: D5:...:EA, auto: false
05-06 22:48:31.814 D/BluetoothGatt(17325): registerApp()
05-06 22:48:31.814 D/BluetoothGatt(17325): registerApp() - UUID=ffbf338d-8200-45f8-83b3-79d71ac40ffd
05-06 22:48:31.816 D/BluetoothGatt(17325): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=7
05-06 22:48:31.820 D/BluetoothGatt(17325): onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=7 device=D5:...:EA
Thread started:  #7
05-06 22:48:31.835 D/BluetoothGatt(17325): onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=7 device=D5:...:EA
Thread started:  #8
```

Comment: I note the thread numbers after those lines are different - possibly relevant?

Comment: @stkent, this is not my threads, system may be.